# ¿Como puedo crear una matrix en ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo una duda con respecto a ruby, aun no logro saber como hacer uso de una matrix. En java puedo hacer esto:

```
int matriz[][] = new int[3][3]
```

y para llegar una matrix por teclado recorro dos for para `matrix[i][j] = dato`.

Ahora quiero implementar lo mismo en ruby, lo cual no logro comprender, porque existe una clase Matrix pero no se como hacer uso de el. Se que tambien en ruby puedo hacer esto:

```
arreglo=[[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[7,8,9]]
```

pero no entiendo como podria llenarlo en un for desde el teclado, alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Por qué votan para cerrar la pregunta como 'No es claro lo que pregunta'?  Con el título es **más** que obvio que la pregunta es muy clara.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes que nada, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, en Ruby no necesitas definir el tamaño de un array para empezar a introducir elementos.

Puedes crear un array:

```
array = []  #=> []
```

E introducir elementos con [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-push) como si de un contenedor genérico se tratara:

```
array.push(1)  #=> [1]
```

O incluso con [`Array#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```
array[2] = 3  #=> [1, nil, 3]
```

Teniendo claro esto, también puedes crear un array con el método [`Array::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-c-new). La ventaja, es que este método recibe dos parámetros opcionales: el primero es el tamaño del array y el segundo es el elemento con el que se rellenará cada elemento por defecto.

De esta forma puedes un array multidimensional vacío:

```
matrix = Array.new(3, [])  #=> [[], [], []]
```

Ahora solo faltaría rellenarla. Este proceso se puede hacer de muchas formas, pero una forma muy parecida a como se podría utilizar en otros lenguajes como Java, sería así:

```
for i in 0...3
  for j in 0...3
    print("matrix[#{i}][#{j}]: ")
    matrix[i][j] = gets.to_i
  end
end
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirvió tu información.

Comment: @Jose si te ha ayudado la respuesta puedes marcar como “aceptada”.  visita el [Recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Una matrix es un conjunto unidimensional de estructuras.
Te aconsejo investigar sobre los tipos de estructuras que existen en Ruby, ya que tienen distintas funcionalidades.

```
Array.new()
```

Básicamente hace la magia para un conunto mutable de elementos no unicos, un arreglo ni siquiera es una estructura de datos, la gente no sabe traducir del inglés una palabra.

```
[] = Array.new
```

Si las mezclas:

```
Array.new(Array.new(), Array.new()) = [[],[]] = Array.new([],[],[]) = [Array.new, Array.new]
```

Se pueden generar de formas mas "dinamicas" utilizando bloques.